# Proving/disproving a matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

I have a matrix:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 4&1 \\ 1&5 \end{bmatrix}
$$

I want to determine whether $A$ is positive definite.

Therefore, I used the definition, $A$ is positive definite iff:

$$
x^*Ax > 0, \forall x \in C^2, x \neq 0
$$

$$
x = [a,b]^t , a,b \in C, a.b \neq 0\\
x^*Ax = [a,b]^tA[a,b] = 4|a|^2 + \bar{b}a + \bar{a}b + 5|b|^2
$$

Now, I know that $z + \bar{z} = 2\operatorname{Re}z \Rightarrow \bar{b}a + \bar{a}b = 2\operatorname{Re}(\bar{b}a)$

But still, I don't know whether I get a positive number for $x^*Ax$, I probably miss something, what am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: It is likely more straightforward to calculate the eigenvalues. A symmetric matrix is positive definite if all its eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that $|a-b|^2 \geq 0$ and $|a+b|^2 \geq 0$, so after expanding, you get the famous inequality
$$
- (|a|^2 + |b|^2) \leq 2 \Re(a \bar{b}) \leq |a|^2 + |b|^2.
$$
Plugging this into your result gives $x^*Ax \geq 3 |a|^2 + 4 |b|^2 \geq 0$.

Another option is to check positive-definiteness by computing the eigenvalues and checking that they are both positive, or by using the characterization with the minors.

Comment: Thank you, helped alot.

Comment: The last statement should be $x^*Ax \ge 3|a|^2 + 4 |b|^2 > 0$ (strictly greater) for $A$ to be positive definite. Otherwise, $A$ would be positive *semi*-definite, which is not the case here because $x\ne0$ implies $\|x\|^2 = |a|^2 + |b|^2>0$, and hence $3|a|^2 + 4 |b|^2 >0$.